# What is a drop-in replacement for Python's `open()` function to read/write a file on S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

What is a good way to replace Python's built-in `open()` function when working with Amazon S3 buckets in an AWS Lambda function?

### Summary

- I am looking for a method to download a file from or upload a file to Amazon S3 in an AWS Lambda function.
- The syntax/API should similar to Python's built-in `open()`, specifically returning a file-like object that could be passed to other functions like `pandas.read_csv()`.

  - I am mostly interested in `read()` and `write()` and not so much `seek()` or `tell()`, which would be be required for `PIL.Image.open()` for example.
- The method should use libraries already available in AWS Lambda, e.g. boto3.
- It should keep the Lambda deployment size small. Thus not a large dependency like [s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is usually overkill for an AWS Lambda.

Here is an example of what I am thinking of.

```py
filename = "s3://mybucket/path/to/file.txt"
outpath = "s3://mybucket/path/to/lowercase.txt"

with s3_open(filename) as fd, s3_open(outpath, "wt") as fout:
    for line in fd:
        fout.write(line.strip().lower())
```

### Motivation

Most people using Python are familiar with

```py
filename = "/path/to/file.txt"
with open(filename) as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()
```

Those using Amazon S3 are also probably familiar with [S3 URIs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/index.html#path-argument-type), but S3 URIs are not convenient for working with [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html), the Amazon S3 Python SDK:

- boto3 uses parameters like `s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)`, whereas I usually have the S3 URI
- boto3 returns a json response, which contains a StreamingBody and all I want is the StreamingBody
- The StreamingBody returns bytes but text is usually more convenient

Many Python libraries accept [file-like objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object), e.g. json, pandas, zipfile.

I often just need to download/upload a single file to S3 so there's no need to manage a whole file system. Nor do I need or want to save the file to disk only to read it back into memory.

### A start

```py
import io
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

def s3uriparse(s3_uri):
    raise NotImplmementedError


def s3_open(s3_uri, mode="rt"):
    bucket, key = s3uriparse(s3_uri)
    
    if mode.startswith("r"):
        r = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        fileobj = r["StreamingBody"]
        if mode.endswith("t"):
            fileobj = io.TextIOWrapper(fileobj._raw_stream)
        return fileobj
    elif mode.startswith("w"):
        # Write mode
        raise NotImplementedError
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid mode")
```

Comment: [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) will S3-enable the `open()` command.

Comment: Yes, smart-open looks pretty good. Would you like to create an answer with an example usage? That way others can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Python library called [smart-open · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/).

It's really good, because you can use all the file-handling commands you're familiar with, and it works with S3 objects! It can also read from compressed files.

```py
>>> from smart_open import open
>>>
>>> # stream lines from an S3 object
>>> for line in open('s3://commoncrawl/robots.txt'):
...    print(repr(line))
...    break
'User-Agent: *\n'

>>> # stream from/to compressed files, with transparent (de)compression:
>>> for line in open('smart_open/tests/test_data/1984.txt.gz', encoding='utf-8'):
...    print(repr(line))
'It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.\n'
'Winston Smith, his chin nuzzled into his breast in an effort to escape the vile\n'
'wind, slipped quickly through the glass doors of Victory Mansions, though not\n'
'quickly enough to prevent a swirl of gritty dust from entering along with him.\n'

>>> # can use context managers too:
>>> with open('smart_open/tests/test_data/1984.txt.gz') as fin:
...    with open('smart_open/tests/test_data/1984.txt.bz2', 'w') as fout:
...        for line in fin:
...           fout.write(line)
74
80
78
79

>>> # can use any IOBase operations, like seek
>>> with open('s3://commoncrawl/robots.txt', 'rb') as fin:
...     for line in fin:
...         print(repr(line.decode('utf-8')))
...         break
...     offset = fin.seek(0)  # seek to the beginning
...     print(fin.read(4))
'User-Agent: *\n'
b'User'

>>> # stream from HTTP
>>> for line in open('http://example.com/index.html'):
...     print(repr(line))
...     break
'<!doctype html>\n'
```

Comment: What about .dat or any complex file read? Can you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287301/how-to-read-dat-file-from-aws-s3-using-mdfreader ?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about your motivation: what is wrong with

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3.Object(bucket_name, full_key)
s3_object.put(Body=byte_stream_of_some_kind)
```

for write and

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3_object_byte_stream = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key)['Body'].read()
```

for stream in the object to your lambda to update?

Both of these functionalities stream straight into or out of s3 - you don't have to download the object then open it in a stream after the fact - if you want to you can still use a with statement with either to close them up automatically (use it on the resource)

There is also no file system in s3 - though we use object keys with a file system like nomenclature (the '/' and that is displayed in the console as if it were directories, the actual layout of the an s3 internally is flat with the names having some parsing ability. So if you know the full key of an object you can stream it into and out of your lambda without any downloading at all

Comment: One thing that's missing here is the ability to use the S3 URI as if it were a standard filename. A lot of data scientists I work with can pick up a CSV file and start doing stuff with it. But they get confused when you point them to a CSV file in S3. Yes, S3 is flat, but the AWS Console and AWS CLI make it appear as if it were a filesystem because they split by `/` by default. It would be preferable to treat S3 like it was, say, a mounted hard drive. That way folks unfamiliar with S3, and who have no reason to learn its inner details, can just use `open(s3_uri)`.

Comment: hah. Okay, I can understand that reasoning - I would prefer to try to educate the people properly, but I also am *quite* aware of how difficult that can be and sometimes its just easier to provide them with tools that they use